# lingpipe sentiment analysis tutorial demo error?

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, lingpipe

I was doing the sentiment analysis a from lingpipe website tutorial, and I keep getting this error, is there anyone wo can help?

```
java -cp "sentimentDemo.jar:../../../lingpipe

e-4.1.0.jar" PolarityBasic file:///Users/dylan/Desktop/POLARITY_DIR/
BASIC POLARITY DEMO

Data Directory=file:/Users/dylan/Desktop/POLARITY_DIR/txt_sentoken
Thrown: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.aliasi.classify.DynamicLMClassifier.createNGramProcess(DynamicLMClassifier.java:313)
at PolarityBasic.<init>(PolarityBasic.java:26)
at PolarityBasic.main(PolarityBasic.java:92)
```

Comment: could you add a link to the tutorial?

Comment: ok this the the webpage http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specified path file:///Users/dylan/Desktop/POLARITY_DIR/ should contain the unpacked data (see tutorial) in the directory txt_sentoken

You can see this in the output:

Data Directory=file:/Users/dylan/Desktop/POLARITY_DIR/txt_sentoken

Also the the tutorial is not setup to use an URL, so the command should be

java -cp sentimentDemo.jar:../../../lingpipe-4.0.jar PolarityBasic /Users/dylan/Desktop/POLARITY_DIR